# How can I write the equation of the parabola passing through list of three points?

Tags: list-manipulation, interpolation

With three points `a = {1, 2}, b = {2, 3}, c={-1, 5}`. I tried to write the equation of parabola passing through given points like this.

```
a = {1, 2};
b = {2, 3};
c = {-1, 5};
{m x^2 + n x + p} /. 
 Solve[{m a[[1]]^2 + n a[[1]] + p == a[[2]], 
   m b[[1]]^2 + n b[[1]] + p == b[[2]], 
   m c[[1]]^2 + n c[[1]] + p == c[[2]] }, {m, n, p}, Reals]
```

> {{8/3 - (3 x)/2 + (5 x^2)/6}}

How can I make equations of a list three points

```
{{{-12, -1}, {-10, -7}, {6, 5}}, {{-12, -1}, {-10, 
   5}, {6, -7}}, {{-12, -1}, {-8, -9}, {4, 7}}, {{-12, -1}, {-8, 
   7}, {4, -9}}, {{-10, -7}, {-8, -9}, {4, 
   7}}, {{-10, -7}, {-8, -9}, {6, 5}}, {{-10, -7}, {-8, 
   7}, {4, -9}}, {{-10, -7}, {-8, 7}, {6, 
   5}}, {{-10, -7}, {-2, -11}, {6, 5}}, {{-10, -7}, {-2, 9}, {6, 
   5}}, {{-10, -7}, {4, -9}, {6, 5}}, {{-10, -7}, {4, 7}, {6, 
   5}}, {{-10, -7}, {6, 5}, {8, -1}}, {{-10, 5}, {-8, -9}, {4, 
   7}}, {{-10, 5}, {-8, -9}, {6, -7}}, {{-10, 5}, {-8, 
   7}, {4, -9}}, {{-10, 5}, {-8, 7}, {6, -7}}, {{-10, 
   5}, {-2, -11}, {6, -7}}, {{-10, 5}, {-2, 9}, {6, -7}}, {{-10, 
   5}, {4, -9}, {6, -7}}, {{-10, 5}, {4, 7}, {6, -7}}, {{-10, 
   5}, {6, -7}, {8, -1}}, {{-8, -9}, {-2, -11}, {4, 
   7}}, {{-8, -9}, {-2, 9}, {4, 7}}, {{-8, -9}, {4, 
   7}, {6, -7}}, {{-8, -9}, {4, 7}, {6, 5}}, {{-8, -9}, {4, 
   7}, {8, -1}}, {{-8, 7}, {-2, -11}, {4, -9}}, {{-8, 7}, {-2, 
   9}, {4, -9}}, {{-8, 7}, {4, -9}, {6, -7}}, {{-8, 7}, {4, -9}, {6, 
   5}}, {{-8, 7}, {4, -9}, {8, -1}}}
```

Comment: Do you know about [Lagrange polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial)?

Comment: No, I do not know.

Comment: Please see answer below, hope this helps!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Lagrange interpolating polynomials](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LagrangeInterpolatingPolynomial.html) are implemented in Mathematica as the [`InterpolatingPolynomial`](https://reference.wolframcloud.com/cloudplatform/ref/InterpolatingPolynomial.html) function. The Lagrange interpolating polynomial is the polynomial of degree $n-1$ that passes through $n$ points.

Solve your example at the three points `a = {1, 2}, b = {2, 3}, c = {-1, 5}` with:

```
InterpolatingPolynomial[{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {-1, 5}}, x]//Expand
```

$$\frac{5 x^2}{6}-\frac{3 x}{2}+\frac{8}{3}$$

Use `InterpolatingPolynomial` to find a polynomial for each set of points, and plot the results.

```
p = {{{-12, -1}, {-10, -7}, {6, 5}}, {{-12, -1}, {-10, 
   5}, {6, -7}}, {{-12, -1}, {-8, -9}, {4, 7}}, {{-12, -1}, {-8, 
   7}, {4, -9}}, {{-10, -7}, {-8, -9}, {4, 
   7}}, {{-10, -7}, {-8, -9}, {6, 5}}, {{-10, -7}, {-8, 
   7}, {4, -9}}, {{-10, -7}, {-8, 7}, {6, 
   5}}, {{-10, -7}, {-2, -11}, {6, 5}}, {{-10, -7}, {-2, 9}, {6, 
   5}}, {{-10, -7}, {4, -9}, {6, 5}}, {{-10, -7}, {4, 7}, {6, 
   5}}, {{-10, -7}, {6, 5}, {8, -1}}, {{-10, 5}, {-8, -9}, {4, 
   7}}, {{-10, 5}, {-8, -9}, {6, -7}}, {{-10, 5}, {-8, 
   7}, {4, -9}}, {{-10, 5}, {-8, 7}, {6, -7}}, {{-10, 
   5}, {-2, -11}, {6, -7}}, {{-10, 5}, {-2, 9}, {6, -7}}, {{-10, 
   5}, {4, -9}, {6, -7}}, {{-10, 5}, {4, 7}, {6, -7}}, {{-10, 
   5}, {6, -7}, {8, -1}}, {{-8, -9}, {-2, -11}, {4, 
   7}}, {{-8, -9}, {-2, 9}, {4, 7}}, {{-8, -9}, {4, 
   7}, {6, -7}}, {{-8, -9}, {4, 7}, {6, 5}}, {{-8, -9}, {4, 
   7}, {8, -1}}, {{-8, 7}, {-2, -11}, {4, -9}}, {{-8, 7}, {-2, 
   9}, {4, -9}}, {{-8, 7}, {4, -9}, {6, -7}}, {{-8, 7}, {4, -9}, {6, 
   5}}, {{-8, 7}, {4, -9}, {8, -1}}};

poly = InterpolatingPolynomial[#, x] &/@ p // Expand;

Plot[poly, {x, -14, 10}, Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> All]
```

[image: plotted polynomial solutions]

```
poly // Short
```

$$\left\{\frac{5 x^2}{24}+\frac{19 x}{12}-12,\langle\langle 30\rangle\rangle ,\frac{5 x^2}{24}-\frac{x}{2}-\frac{31}{3}\right\}$$

Answer (score 5):

We can define a [Lagrange polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial) of order 2:

```
LagrangePolynomial[{{x1_, y1_}, {x2_, y2_}, {x3_, y3_}}, x_] =
  ((x - x2) (x - x3))/((x1 - x2) (x1 - x3)) * y1 +
  ((x - x1) (x - x3))/((x2 - x1) (x2 - x3)) * y2 +
  ((x - x1) (x - x2))/((x3 - x1) (x3 - x2)) * y3;

P = {{{-12, -1}, {-10, -7}, {6, 5}},  {{-12, -1}, {-10, 5}, {6, -7}},
     {{-12, -1}, {-8, -9}, {4, 7}},   {{-12, -1}, {-8, 7}, {4, -9}},
     {{-10, -7}, {-8, -9}, {4, 7}},   {{-10, -7}, {-8, -9}, {6, 5}},
     {{-10, -7}, {-8, 7}, {4, -9}},   {{-10, -7}, {-8, 7}, {6, 5}},
     {{-10, -7}, {-2, -11}, {6, 5}},  {{-10, -7}, {-2, 9}, {6, 5}},
     {{-10, -7}, {4, -9}, {6, 5}},    {{-10, -7}, {4, 7}, {6, 5}},
     {{-10, -7}, {6, 5}, {8, -1}},    {{-10, 5}, {-8, -9}, {4, 7}},
     {{-10, 5}, {-8, -9}, {6, -7}},   {{-10, 5}, {-8, 7}, {4, -9}},
     {{-10, 5}, {-8, 7}, {6, -7}},    {{-10, 5}, {-2, -11}, {6, -7}},
     {{-10, 5}, {-2, 9}, {6, -7}},    {{-10, 5}, {4, -9}, {6, -7}},
     {{-10, 5}, {4, 7}, {6, -7}},     {{-10, 5}, {6, -7}, {8, -1}},
     {{-8, -9}, {-2, -11}, {4, 7}},   {{-8, -9}, {-2, 9}, {4, 7}},
     {{-8, -9}, {4, 7}, {6, -7}},     {{-8, -9}, {4, 7}, {6, 5}},
     {{-8, -9}, {4, 7}, {8, -1}},     {{-8, 7}, {-2, -11}, {4, -9}},
     {{-8, 7}, {-2, 9}, {4, -9}},     {{-8, 7}, {4, -9}, {6, -7}},
     {{-8, 7}, {4, -9}, {6, 5}},      {{-8, 7}, {4, -9}, {8, -1}}};

Expand[LagrangePolynomial[#, x]] & /@ P
(*    {-12 + (19 x)/12 + (5 x^2)/24,    10 - (19 x)/12 - (5 x^2)/24,
       -5 + (13 x)/6 + (5 x^2)/24,      3 - (13 x)/6 - (5 x^2)/24,
       -(11/3) + 2 x + x^2/6,           -7 + (5 x)/4 + x^2/8,
       323/21 - (26 x)/7 - (25 x^2)/42, 191/7 - (29 x)/28 - (25 x^2)/56,
       -(71/8) + (11 x)/8 + (5 x^2)/32, 79/8 + x/8 - (5 x^2)/32,
       -(184/7) + (71 x)/28 + (25 x^2)/56, 8 + x/4 - x^2/8,
       13 - x/12 - (5 x^2)/24,          -(365/21) + (26 x)/7 + (25 x^2)/42,
       -(205/7) + (29 x)/28 + (25 x^2)/56, 5/3 - 2 x - x^2/6,
       5 - (5 x)/4 - x^2/8,             -(95/8) - x/8 + (5 x^2)/32,
       55/8 - (11 x)/8 - (5 x^2)/32,    -10 - x/4 + x^2/8,
       170/7 - (71 x)/28 - (25 x^2)/56, -15 + x/12 + (5 x^2)/24,
       -(65/9) + (22 x)/9 + (5 x^2)/18, 95/9 + (2 x)/9 - (5 x^2)/18,
       145/7 - (22 x)/21 - (25 x^2)/42, 7 + (2 x)/3 - x^2/6,
       25/3 + x/2 - (5 x^2)/24,         -(113/9) - (2 x)/9 + (5 x^2)/18,
       47/9 - (22 x)/9 - (5 x^2)/18,    -9 - (2 x)/3 + x^2/6,
       -(159/7) + (22 x)/21 + (25 x^2)/42, -(31/3) - x/2 + (5 x^2)/24}    *)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
list = 
    {{{-12, -1}, {-10, -7}, {6, 5}}, {{-12, -1}, {-10, 
     5}, {6, -7}}, {{-12, -1}, {-8, -9}, {4, 7}}, {{-12, -1}, {-8, 
     7}, {4, -9}}, {{-10, -7}, {-8, -9}, {4, 
     7}}, {{-10, -7}, {-8, -9}, {6, 5}}, {{-10, -7}, {-8, 
     7}, {4, -9}}, {{-10, -7}, {-8, 7}, {6, 
     5}}, {{-10, -7}, {-2, -11}, {6, 5}}, {{-10, -7}, {-2, 9}, {6, 
     5}}, {{-10, -7}, {4, -9}, {6, 5}}, {{-10, -7}, {4, 7}, {6, 
     5}}, {{-10, -7}, {6, 5}, {8, -1}}, {{-10, 5}, {-8, -9}, {4, 
     7}}, {{-10, 5}, {-8, -9}, {6, -7}}, {{-10, 5}, {-8, 
     7}, {4, -9}}, {{-10, 5}, {-8, 7}, {6, -7}}, {{-10, 
     5}, {-2, -11}, {6, -7}}, {{-10, 5}, {-2, 9}, {6, -7}}, {{-10, 
     5}, {4, -9}, {6, -7}}, {{-10, 5}, {4, 7}, {6, -7}}, {{-10, 
     5}, {6, -7}, {8, -1}}, {{-8, -9}, {-2, -11}, {4, 
     7}}, {{-8, -9}, {-2, 9}, {4, 7}}, {{-8, -9}, {4, 
     7}, {6, -7}}, {{-8, -9}, {4, 7}, {6, 5}}, {{-8, -9}, {4, 
     7}, {8, -1}}, {{-8, 7}, {-2, -11}, {4, -9}}, {{-8, 7}, {-2, 
     9}, {4, -9}}, {{-8, 7}, {4, -9}, {6, -7}}, {{-8, 7}, {4, -9}, {6,
      5}}, {{-8, 7}, {4, -9}, {8, -1}}};


sol[{a_, b_, c_}] :=
 Solve[{
   m a[[1]]^2 + n a[[1]] + p == a[[2]], 
   m b[[1]]^2 + n b[[1]] + p == b[[2]], 
   m c[[1]]^2 + n c[[1]] + p == c[[2]]}, {m, n, p}, Reals]

res = sol /@ list;

f = m x^2 + n x + p;

leq = f /. res

leq // Short
```

[image]

Show all parabolas:

```
Plot[leq, {x, -10, 10}, PlotStyle -> Directive[Thin, Black]]
```

[image]

Show first 5 parabolas:

```
Plot[Evaluate @ leq[[1 ;; 5]], {x, -10, 10},
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]

Does the first parabola pass through the first point triple?

```
Plot[leq[[1]], {x, -20, 20},
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.02], Point /@ list[[1]]}]
```

[image]